# format listview column from numeric to int

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listview populated  by this code :

```
if (popula.Rows.Count > 0)
{
     foreach (DataRow row in popula.Rows)
     {
         listView1.Items.Add(row[0].ToString());
         listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(row[1].ToString());
         listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(row[2].ToString());
         listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(row[3].ToString());
         listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(row[4].ToString());
     }
```

The first column is numeric with this format :

```
  Code
 ------------- 
  69675.0000
   6078.0000
  57536.0000
  37625.0000
  54079.0000
  57933.0000
  51968.0000
  59160.0000
  25392.0000
```

I want o display only :

```
69675
 6078
```

i dont like to show the zeros and the point. maybe sonthing like this

```
 listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add.format ((row[4].ToString()));
```

Blam i have write

```
 listView1.Items.Add(row[0].ToString("F0"));
```

and show me this error : 'No overload for  method 'Testing' take 1 argument.

I have add

```
 using system.globalization;
```

but still show me error;

Comment: I have the similar question too, except im doing it in Android Java, I don't want to mess with the sharedPreference, or my arrayList, I just want it to affect the ListView adapter to show the whole number instead of 254.0

Answer (score 1):

When you do `number.ToString()` on double or floating point numbers it defaults to a certain number of decimal places.

You can change this by adding a format string parameter to the `ToString` call like so:

```
((double)row[4]).ToString("F0")
```

`F` reffers to a Fixed-point format, and the number after refers to how many digits it will display after the point. So `F0` is a fixed point number with no digits after the point, basically an Integer.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#FFormatString

Comment: There is no ToString overload on object that takes a string in parameter, there's one on double though.

Comment: What if you unbox the cell as a double first, like my updated answer?

Comment: Ahh, good. Forgot that the cells were stored as objects not doubles, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Using [linq to dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) (make sur you have System.Data.DataSetExtensions in your references):

```
const string format = "D";
Func<DataRow, int, string> formatter = 
  (DataRow row, int index) => row.Field<double>(index).ToString(format);

foreach (DataRow row in popula.AsEnumerable())
{
  var item = listView1.Items.Add(formatter(row, 0));

  for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
  {
    item.SubItems.Add(formatter(row, i));
  }
}
```